# how to use xaml graphic inside the application resource?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, svg, staticresource

I have an XAML graphic that converted from vector graphic (SVG) already. The way i want to use it is make XAML file for each image then put it in some folder in the project. Inside the application.resources, make a reference key to use it within the project.

The problem i found it seem what i did in the application.resources is wrong. I used

> 'ResourceDictionary'

but it throw an exception.

> > 'Set property 'System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.Source' threw an exception.'

Please help me how to do this.
Thank you in advance.

I want to use the xaml image in the resources file (in my project is app.xaml) inside the Application.Resources, then the other page can refer this as StaticResource

Additional, I want to use this image as button.

I have the following xaml, and i saved it to a new file as 'button.xaml'. Then I want to add a reference link in the application.resources to use this button in the other page as a button.

```
<Viewbox xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" Stretch="Uniform"><Canvas Name="Layer_2" Width="609" Height="757" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0"><Canvas.RenderTransform><TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0"/></Canvas.RenderTransform><Canvas.Resources/><!--Unknown tag: metadata--><!--Unknown tag: sodipodi:namedview--><Canvas Name="g3"><Canvas Name="g5"><Path xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Name="path7" Fill="#FFAF946D"><Path.Data><PathGeometry Figures="M256.721 112.144c-0.616-2.478-2.333-8.133-5.919-12.168c-0.219-0.247-0.276-0.906 0.349-1.113    c1.241-0.413 3.354-0.915 4.918-0.236c0.342 0.148 0.907-0.111 0.859-0.481c-0.71-5.537-6.52-10.925-10.595-11.907    c-0.432-0.104-0.818-0.417-0.176-0.739c1.43-0.717 4.007-1.752 5.76-0.974c0.287 0.127 0.604-0.138 0.495-0.465    c-1.686-5.043-6.322-8.537-16.146-11.298c-0.26-0.073-0.657-0.538-0.325-0.952c0.912-1.141 3.307-3.001 8.446-0.909    c0.371 0.151 0.747-0.245 0.506-0.617c-4-6.191-14.502-10.717-28.461-10.982c-0.433-0.008-0.969-0.316-0.164-0.659    c0.859-0.366 2.25-0.775 4.329-0.906c0.435-0.027 0.463-0.576 0.009-0.835c-8.062-4.602-14.098-7.61-36.706-5.506    c-0.247 0.023-0.704-0.207-0.536-0.641c0.431-1.113 1.688-3.258 5.18-4.41c0.495-0.164 0.521-0.694-0.014-0.805    c-9.716-2.006-16.028 1.253-23.719 5.46c-0.362 0.198-0.973 0.163-0.616-0.583c0.513-1.07 1.51-2.776 3.324-4.736    c0.218-0.235 0.018-0.712-0.32-0.702c-8.369 0.237-17.41 3.461-26.267 11.968c-0.279 0.268-0.867 0.435-0.862-0.163    c0.01-1.217 0.165-3.315 1.016-4.829c0.188-0.333-0.073-0.863-0.463-0.792c-5.211 0.953-12.42 8.045-15.353 15.061    c-0.122 0.292-0.686 0.476-0.812 0.249c-0.885-1.591-0.364-4.012 0.07-5.422c0.21-0.683-0.316-0.756-0.7-0.532    c-5.949 3.467-15.856 12.94-15.856 27.901c-5.96 3.221-9.458 8.835-9.458 13.541c-2.212 2.212-13.048-5.441-20.368-1.622    c-6.353 3.315-8.392 16.198 0.757 25.38c-5.604 6.426-10.652 11.246-16.033 16.628c-5.528 5.528-11.396 5.264-15.648 6.016h-0.003    c-2.727 0.48-4.79 1.381-5.671 4.486c-1.712 6.028 0.7 11.97 5.69 17.555c4.821 5.395 12.042 10.454 20.275 14.941    c0.633 3.275-0.172 6.951-2.416 9.194c-3.5 3.501 0 9.951 11.457 9.951c8.656 0 15.575 0.268 20.61-6.518    c11.094 3.667 21.293 5.974 27.763 6.433c5.707 0.4 12.106-0.637 18.624-2.808c2.718 3.695 2.463 9.882-0.761 13.105    c-3.501 3.501 2.106 12.059 13.563 12.059s25.804-0.538 31.586-16.311c2.147-5.851 7.522-9.881 13.417-12.972    c0.264-0.139 1.025 0.136 1.153 0.402c1.796 3.746 5.314 6.608 9.935 6.608c13.691 0 25.46-7.994 28.006-21.545    c2.546-13.548-0.318-27.868 7.638-41.235c3.322-5.579 5.376-16.652 4.348-29.047c-0.023-0.273 0.414-0.775 0.659-0.743    c1.024 0.135 2.056 0.369 2.879 0.767C256.374 112.881 256.915 112.924 256.721 112.144z" FillRule="NonZero"/></Path.Data></Path><Path xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Name="path9" Stroke="#FFCDAD7F" StrokeLineJoin="Round" StrokeStartLineCap="Round" StrokeEndLineCap="Round"><Path.Data><PathGeometry Figures="M214.991 180.538    c-10.025 0-14.002 5.988-13.804 11.977" FillRule="NonZero"/></Path.Data></Path></Canvas><Path xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Name="path11" Fill="#FFA48C67"><Path.Data><PathGeometry Figures="M211.39 151.48c-0.91-1.93-2.36-3.55-4-5.07c-2.46-2.28-5.42-4.34-7.94-6.38c-1.25-1.02-2.4-2.03-3.3-3   c-0.44-0.48-0.82-0.95-1.14-1.4c0.24-0.14 0.48-0.27 0.7-0.37c0.28-0.13 0.53-0.19 0.58-0.19c0.57-0.07 1.07-0.22 1.63-0.55   c0.28-0.18 0.57-0.4 0.84-0.77c0.27-0.35 0.51-0.9 0.51-1.51c0-0.11-0.01-0.22-0.02-0.32c-0.23-1.79-0.91-3.79-2.13-5.78   c-0.6-0.97-1.33-1.94-2.21-2.87c0.31 0.1 0.61 0.15 0.89 0.15c0.65 0 1.21-0.17 1.75-0.53c0.27-0.19 0.54-0.43 0.77-0.79   c0.22-0.34 0.39-0.82 0.39-1.33c0-0.15-0.01-0.3-0.04-0.45c-0.52-2.87-2.19-5.41-4.61-7.37c-1.76-1.44-3.92-2.6-6.4-3.46   c0.47 0.08 0.94 0.2 1.41 0.39c0.31 0.13 0.65 0.21 1.01 0.21c0.69 0 1.4-0.31 1.85-0.81c0.46-0.5 0.68-1.15 0.68-1.76   c0-0.51-0.15-1-0.38-1.42c-0.88-1.56-1.96-3.14-3.29-4.61c-1.34-1.47-2.94-2.85-4.86-4.04c-3.2-1.98-7.27-3.39-12.41-3.92   c0.27-0.28 0.49-0.56 0.64-0.88c0.18-0.38 0.3-0.8 0.3-1.3c0-0.31-0.05-0.66-0.2-1.02c-0.15-0.36-0.4-0.73-0.74-1   c-1.65-1.36-3.61-2.47-6-3.21c-2.4-0.74-5.21-1.12-8.66-1.12c-0.67 0-1.37 0.02-2.09 0.05c0.15-0.32 0.23-0.67 0.23-1.03   c0-0.59-0.22-1.17-0.58-1.59c-0.35-0.43-0.8-0.71-1.25-0.88c-2.45-0.89-5.12-1.32-7.82-1.33c-3.58 0.01-7.22 0.78-10.47 2.32v-0.01   c-0.01-0.62-0.16-1.18-0.54-1.74c-0.19-0.28-0.45-0.55-0.81-0.78c-0.36-0.22-0.83-0.37-1.31-0.37c-0.06 0-0.14 0.01-0.23 0.01   c-0.01 0-0.03 0-0.04 0.01h-0.01c-1.87 0.16-3.65 0.56-5.35 1.14c-1.71 0.58-3.34 1.34-4.91 2.26c-1.51 0.88-2.96 1.91-4.39 3.03   c-0.12-0.44-0.34-0.84-0.66-1.17c-0.48-0.5-1.2-0.81-1.93-0.8c-0.16 0-0.33 0.01-0.49 0.04c-2.29 0.38-4.4 1.07-6.31 1.98   c-0.05 0.74-0.08 1.5-0.08 2.28c-5.96 3.22-9.46 8.84-9.46 13.54c-2.21 2.21-13.04-5.44-20.36-1.62c-6.36 3.32-8.4 16.2 0.75 25.38   c-5.6 6.43-10.65 11.25-16.03 16.63c-5.53 5.53-11.4 5.26-15.65 6.01c-1.36 0.24-2.56 0.59-3.53 1.26   c-0.97 0.68-1.7 1.68-2.14 3.23c-1.71 6.03 0.7 11.97 5.69 17.56c4.82 5.39 12.04 10.45 20.27 14.94c0.15 0.77 0.22 1.57 0.21 2.37   c8.87 4.74 18.75 8.78 28.06 11.89c0.47-0.49 0.93-1.04 1.38-1.64c11.1 3.67 21.3 5.98 27.77 6.44c5.7 0.4 12.1-0.64 18.62-2.81   c0.4 0.54 0.73 1.14 0.99 1.77c3.94-1.33 7.9-3.05 11.77-5.1c3.99-2.11 7.89-4.57 11.58-7.31c7.03-5.22 13.28-11.45 17.94-18.28   c0.79 0.1 1.58 0.17 2.37 0.17c5.41-0.01 10.66-2.13 14.88-5.01c2.11-1.45 3.97-3.09 5.46-4.82c1.49-1.74 2.63-3.54 3.26-5.4   c0.28-0.85 0.42-1.71 0.42-2.55C212.22 153.79 211.9 152.58 211.39 151.48z" FillRule="NonZero"/></Path.Data></Path><Path xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Name="path13" Fill="#FFCDAD7F"><Path.Data><PathGeometry Figures="M192.386 135.029c0 0 2.153-1.79 3.7-1.947c0.516-0.052 1.243-0.4 1.178-0.909   c-0.382-2.963-2.312-6.974-6.734-10.063c-0.624-0.436-0.993-1.443 0.389-1.481s3.116 0.084 4.525 0.722   c0.526 0.238 1.357-0.142 1.259-0.671c-0.858-4.659-5.421-8.482-12.428-10.077c-0.504-0.115-1.355-1.423-1.014-1.844   c1.165-1.436 4.022-1.781 6.569-0.727c0.559 0.231 1-0.333 0.653-0.948c-3.293-5.84-9.229-11.391-22.084-11.786   c-0.484-0.015-1.332-0.766-0.714-1.536c0.463-0.579 1.189-1.173 2.31-1.482c0.492-0.135 0.863-1.031 0.408-1.405   c-4.027-3.31-9.765-4.822-21.92-3.253c-0.586 0.076-1.52-0.41-0.641-1.152c0.878-0.742 2.352-1.566 4.731-1.896   c0.68-0.094 0.83-0.862 0.061-1.144c-6.428-2.357-14.969-1.247-20.443 3.202c-0.424 0.345-1.249 0.502-0.964-0.462   c0.244-0.824 0.721-1.92 1.651-3.148c0.356-0.47 0.043-1.433-0.56-1.38c-6.843 0.597-12.425 4.499-18.018 9.872   c-0.455 0.438-1.387 0.522-1.032-0.653c0.314-1.041 0.923-2.361 2.102-3.643c0.423-0.46 0.037-1.209-0.668-1.09   c-2.49 0.418-4.747 1.224-6.73 2.293c-5.96 3.221-9.458 8.835-9.458 13.541c-2.212 2.212-13.048-5.441-20.368-1.622   c-6.353 3.315-8.392 16.198 0.757 25.38c-5.604 6.426-10.652 11.246-16.033 16.628c-5.528 5.528-11.396 5.264-15.648 6.016h-0.003   c-2.727 0.48-4.79 1.381-5.671 4.486c-1.712 6.028 0.7 11.97 5.69 17.555c4.821 5.395 12.042 10.454 20.275 14.941   c9.264 5.051 19.811 9.376 29.651 12.628c11.094 3.667 21.293 5.974 27.763 6.433c5.707 0.4 12.106-0.637 18.624-2.808   c15.75-5.238 32.207-17.067 41.337-31.07c10.699 2.113 22.761-6.795 25.011-13.541   C212.764 148.396 195.578 142.667 192.386 135.029z M138.976 177.193c-2.183 10.477-6.828 15.627-16.567 18.368   c-1.688 0.476-3.551 0.716-5.538 0.716c-8.825 0-20.323-4.741-32.376-13.352c-1.997-1.427-1.837-2.754-1.675-3.259   c0.208-0.651 0.871-1.348 2.103-1.348c0.43 0 0.908 0.084 1.421 0.251c8.156 2.644 15.996 3.984 23.3 3.984   c10.237 0 19.07-2.634 25.543-7.614c0.429-0.331 0.938-0.505 1.47-0.505c0 0 0 0 0 0c0.718 0 1.414 0.329 1.862 0.88   C138.949 175.843 139.115 176.526 138.976 177.193z" FillRule="NonZero"/></Path.Data></Path><Path xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Name="path15" Fill="#FFE2CFB4"><Path.Data><PathGeometry Figures="M182.982 170.734C163.284 172.37 149 158.455 149 145c0-13.601-14.678-23.525-30.512-11.484   c-0.331 0.251-1.225 0.458-1.22-0.58c0.016-3.513 0.26-12.719-6.257-17.546c-7.294-5.404-18.862-4.322-32.108 10.33   c-5.604 6.426-10.652 11.246-16.033 16.628c-5.528 5.528-11.396 5.264-15.648 6.016h-0.003c-2.727 0.48-4.79 1.381-5.671 4.486   c-1.712 6.028 0.7 11.97 5.69 17.555c4.821 5.395 12.042 10.454 20.275 14.941c9.264 5.051 19.811 9.376 29.651 12.628   c11.094 3.667 21.293 5.974 27.763 6.433c5.707 0.4 12.106-0.637 18.624-2.808c15.096-5.021 30.842-16.097 40.163-29.338   C184.118 171.688 183.612 170.682 182.982 170.734z M137.73 176.934c-2.07 9.934-6.242 14.75-15.666 17.402   c-9.051 2.548-22.646-2.314-36.829-12.446c-1.972-1.409-1.461-2.815 0.717-2.109c21.796 7.066 39.442 4.303 50.012-3.832   C136.771 175.327 137.925 175.999 137.73 176.934z" FillRule="NonZero"/></Path.Data></Path><Path xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Name="path17" Fill="#FF77461C"><Path.Data><PathGeometry Figures="M95.331 128.664c0 1.758-1.425 3.183-3.182 3.183c-1.758 0-3.183-1.425-3.183-3.183   c0-1.757 1.425-3.183 3.183-3.183C93.906 125.481 95.331 126.907 95.331 128.664z M131.896 150.029   c-1.757 0-3.182 1.425-3.182 3.182c0 1.758 1.425 3.183 3.182 3.183c1.758 0 3.183-1.425 3.183-3.183   C135.079 151.454 133.653 150.029 131.896 150.029z" FillRule="NonZero"/></Path.Data></Path><Path xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Name="path19" Fill="#FF77461C"><Path.Data><PathGeometry Figures="M47.222 148.364c10.381-1.566 25.695 7.363 23.789 12.761c-1.907 5.401-8.911 10.982-23.773 9.28   c-4.99-5.585-7.402-11.526-5.69-17.555c0.882-3.105 2.944-4.006 5.671-4.486H47.222z" FillRule="NonZero"/></Path.Data></Path><Ellipse xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Canvas.Left="92.9" Canvas.Top="127" Width="1.2" Height="1.2" Name="circle21" Fill="#FFA58060"/><Ellipse xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Canvas.Left="132.9" Canvas.Top="152.1" Width="1.2" Height="1.2" Name="circle23" Fill="#FFA58060"/></Canvas></Canvas></Viewbox>
```

Comment: You're not making much sense ... what's the problem, what's the error, what are you trying to do?

Comment: I just edited the question. please let me know if the detail i told is still unclear.

Answer (score 4):

OK, I'm still not sure about the `inside the then the other page`, but let me try to help nevertheless.

Lest assume you have in your `App.Xaml` something like this:

```
<Application.Resources>

  <Canvas x:Key="TestImage">
    <Path Fill="#ff000000" Data="F1 M 68.240234,42.634277 L 69.554688,6.311035 L 69.414063,7.050293 C 69.665039,6.368164 70.482422,5.000000 71.210938,5.000000 L 79.306641,5.000000 C 80.060547,5.000000 80.898438,6.468750 81.104492,7.052734 L 80.963867,6.326172 L 82.497070,42.649414 L 84.995117,40.043945 L 65.742188,40.043945 L 68.240234,42.634277 Z M 87.493164,42.438477 L 85.959961,6.115234 L 85.944336,5.741211 L 85.819336,5.388672 C 85.113281,3.387207 82.946289,0.000000 79.306641,0.000000 L 71.210938,0.000000 C 67.566406,0.000000 65.401367,3.388672 64.697266,5.391113 L 64.571289,5.750000 L 64.556641,6.130371 L 63.244141,42.453613 L 63.150391,45.043945 L 65.742188,45.043945 L 84.995117,45.043945 L 87.602539,45.043945 L 87.493164,42.438477 Z"/>
  </Canvas>

</Application.Resources>
```

Please note it's a path, in a canvas (so, it will draw something if you put it in something), and the important bit is the `x:Key="TestImage`.

Now, lets assume that in a different place/page/control, you want to use that image, that you put in the resource above, all you'll have to do is something like:

```
<Grid>
    <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource TestImage}" />
</Grid>
```

And you'll see your image.

You could have the definition in a different xaml file, in a `ResourceDictionary`, just be sure you merge that dictionary into the resources, so it can be found.

(It'll look like :

```
<Page.Resources>
  <ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
      <ResourceDictionary Source="your_file_name_here.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
  </ResourceDictionary>
</Page.Resources>
```

see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa350178%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more details.

**Edit:**
The canvas you added does not have key... you should have that inside a resource dictionary, and it should have a key, so you can refer to it as `StaticResource`

**Another edit ...**
You will want to have this code in the window/usercontrol you want to access the code in:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="FolderNameHere/weight.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

(if you're in a usercontrol, change the Window to user control obviously ...)
Note there's no `/` or `\` before the folder name (assuming you have your weight in a folder named `FolderNameHere`, you'll reach it by using the above code.

And yes, the code you put in the end will go in that file, and the file will look like:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<Canvas x:Key="TestCanvas" >
    <Path Fill="#ff000000" Data="all the points go here"/>
</Canvas>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Only you'll have something else instead of the Canvas.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I don't want to add the all xaml code of the image in the application.resources. But I still found a problem with the way you suggest me to use a MergerdDictionaries. It seem the project cannot find the xaml file.

Comment: This is why you would use an external dictionary, and merge them, as I suggested at the end. Please have a look at the link I've attached there.

Comment: I have a question about the file that i have to use with MergedDictionaries. Can I put all the code that i wrote in the question? Should I add something new in the code? (Key?) And How to reference the file in the MergedDictionaries? I add like this `<ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/weight.xaml"/>` it doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you for your help again. I will tell you when I try it. I have to in another part first.

Comment: So, did you check it?