# Using vector graphics from Inkscape in WPF in a resource effective matter

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

This question aims to be a best practice on how to use images created with Inkscape and saved as XAML.

There are many articles on the internet but not many of them show the pro and cons of each solution. [Example 1](https://learnwpf.com/post/2006/06/04/How-do-I-Include-Vector-Based-Image-Resources-in-my-WPF-Application.aspx), [Example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19788073/how-to-use-xaml-graphic-inside-the-application-resource)

When you create an image with Inkscape and save as XAML you'll only have a Viewbox inside an XAML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--This file is NOT compatible with Silverlight-->
<Viewbox xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" Stretch="Uniform">
  <Canvas Name="svg8" Width="210" Height="297">
    <Canvas.RenderTransform>
      <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0"/>
    </Canvas.RenderTransform>
    <Canvas.Resources/>
    <!--Unknown tag: sodipodi:namedview-->
    <!--Unknown tag: metadata-->
    <Canvas Name="layer1">
      <Rectangle xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Canvas.Left="55.184521" Canvas.Top="113.30357" Width="33.261906" Height="33.261906" Name="rect4485" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" StrokeThickness="5.29166651" Stroke="#FF000000" StrokeMiterLimit="4"/>
    </Canvas>
  </Canvas>
</Viewbox>
```

To use this file I'd normally have to wrap it in a `ResourceDictionary`. This is annoying because I cannot edit the file in Inkscape anymore without having to remove the `ResourceDictionary` before.

The image will be shown multiple times, for example in a `ListViewItem` or any other element that has an `ItemsSource`.

*Is there a way to have only one `ResourceDictionary` where I can import all of these XAML files?*

Let's assume I have wrapped it in a `ResourceDictionary` and given the `Viewbox` a `x:Key="SquareIcon"` value.

What is most resource effective way of showing this element?

Should I use a `ContentPresenter` and set its `Content` property and set the `Canvas` `x:Shared="false"`?

Is it more effective to use a `Label` (or some other control)?

Maybe remove the `Viewbox` and always use the `Canvas` in a `Viewbox` in my own view?

Should I wrap the `Viewbox` in a `ControlTemplate` and use it in `ContentPresenter` `Template` property? This way I don't need to use the `x:Shared` attribute on `Canvas`.

Comment: What I have found with using vector graphics generated through the Inkscape is that it will use the same names for brushes used within the graphical object. So even if you create separate dictionary for each graphic object, names will conflict in the xaml when parsing `MergedDictionaries`. That's just FYI. You could possibly create a massive file with all of the graphical objects and just import it as 1 file. Then at least naming won't be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

When saving an asset from Inkscape as xaml, you can copy it to `Blend` and then convert it to `Path`. Then you have a vector representation of that asset, which you can easily incorporate as a `style`.

You can read about converting to path [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295055.aspx)

Keep in mind that you can also combine several elements and then convert them. Basically, any kind of image that is in one color can be converted to a single path.

As far as best practice goes, I like to keep all of my Path/Image/Icon related styles in a single `ResourceDictionary` and then reference it globally in `App.xaml` file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create it manually by reading all your files. Steps are next:
1) You have your resources in your project with xaml or svg

2) Create your [markup extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/markup-extensions-and-wpf-xaml) which will provide a value of Geometry by a path of your embedded resource file with an icon. (it should parse and provide value)

3) Create a custom control **IconControl** for displaying icons with dependency property **IconPath** (String) and bind it in your template by [template binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cc189062(v=vs.95).aspx)

```
  <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="controls:IconControl">
                <Viewbox ><!--Could be other container -->
                     <Path Data="{TemplateBinding IconPath}"
                      Fill="{StaticResource DefaultBrush}" />
                </Viewbox>
            </ControlTemplate>
```

Viewbox isnt so good, because it applies transformations to content. So you should use simpliest container to achive good performance.

4)Use your control in markup

```
<IconControl IconPath={locl:IconSvgMarkupExtension PathToYourEmbededResourceHere}/>
```

*I wrote it without VS, from memory, so there could be some mistakes.*

> Should I wrap the Viewbox in a ControlTemplate and use it in
>   ContentPresenter Template property? This way I don't need to use the
>   x:Shared attribute on Canvas.

It is also a possible case, a few years ago I've used the same approach without  so each of my icons was ContentControl with different Template for it depending on Icon.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue : Inkscape svg saved as XAML does not work for me.

After some long search I found this very quick but useful video on Youtube :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=otEV-skBqyI

combine with the converter available on Github here : https://github.com/BerndK/SvgToXaml

used to convert **svg** to a **DrawingImage** ressource
(available thanks BerndK)

It solves my issue !

Just then have to save the ressource file as .xaml in my project

content of Xaml file

```
<ResourceDictionary
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    
    <DrawingImage x:Key="MyVectorImageName">
        <DrawingImage.Drawing>
            <DrawingGroup ClipGeometry="M0,0 V297 H210 V0 H0 Z">
.... //this part is the DrawingImage content Iget in converter and I copied pasted 
</ResourceDictionary>
```

And to use it :

```
<Grid x:Name="gridImage" Margin="0,62.8,0,0" >
                                <!-- Add vector ressource and display it  -->

                                <Grid.Resources>
                                    <ResourceDictionary>
                                        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                                            <ResourceDictionary Source="images/MyVectorImageName.xaml"/>
                                        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                                    </ResourceDictionary>
                                </Grid.Resources> 
                                <Image x:Name="imgName" Source="{StaticResource MyVectorImageName}"/>
                            </Grid>
```

*Note :* I added it as a local ressouce not a global one (but i is possible too)

Answer (score 0):

Using Inkscape 0.92 you may also activate the menu
Edit -> XML-Editor to get at least the Path and some properties to use it in XAML code.